# How to find private keys on Remix ide

Tags: solidity, remix, private-key

I want to sign a message on Remix and I can't find the pair of private/public key.

For example - I going to Deploy & Run Transactions, then trying to "Sign a message using this account key" with the string "Hello! This is my message." and then I found the following result:

hash:
0x9f012ca5b89a316ab213cf1f9cc4d9c6f780387e804c6f82bf01ed30e6658aaf

signature:
0x6a20ade1580a5e7f6a8f02705223e887b104f4ea088bc042bbae6e808668439f1bcbd97af06eb482cccc1510d215d484cd1e09acff46fed1d170ec1ba0e7996100

I need to verify the authenticity of the message with another account, then I need to know the sender public key...

Can anyone help me to find it?

Comment: Duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78040/is-there-a-way-to-view-the-private-key-of-test-account-in-remix-javascript-vm

Answer (score 0):

[The code responsible for these accounts can be found here](https://github.com/ethereum/remix/blob/a044b3435242bfc82b51fc11906f90254e4908d5/remix-simulator/src/methods/accounts.js#L10)

I'll load up web3 soon to extract the private/public keys.

EDIT: this gives different accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect Remix to your local Ganache instance. This way, from Remix, you will be able to sign a message, go back to your Ganache, and use the private key of your account to verify the signature.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are asking for Virtual Js Machine accounts. At the moment I am not able to answer that properly, even if I’m sure it can be done in some simple way, for instance opening the developer console under chrome and inspecting, but the simplest thing to do is to install a local blockchain simulator on the workstation and to work in that space. The obvious choice can be Ganache. If you use the windows based version the data you are searching for are readable in a very simple manner. I personally work in this way.