# Is there a way to view the private key of test account in Remix (javascript VM)

Tags: solidity, remix, private-key

Seeing how the keys are random and those "100 ethers" aren't real I can't think of why this is not obvious functionality, I'll need this for many reasons.

Comment: This was covered by https://github.com/ethereum/remix/issues/685. A functionality was added to allow message signing, but not expose the private key. So I think you're out of luck.

Comment: hm i see...thanks. I just saw the message signing but not the private key unless there's a way to get the key from signed message which i don't think it's possible.

Comment: No, that's not possible, else you'd be able to get everyone's private keys from any messages they sent :-\

Comment: Well, it's just native JS code, so the private key will be in there *somewhere*.  I had a very quick look but there's nearly 300,000 lines of somewhat-minified code and nearly 500 variables/functions called `privateKey`  If you're desperate you could breakpoint every single one of them until you got lucky?

Comment: interesting...i have written small c# app that converts ec key to address via nethereum..i guess i should put those 500 to see...i doubt it's possible but yeah if i am desperate will try later.

Comment: Had another go.  Partial success.  Search for "privateKey=crypto.randomBytes(32);" or "privateKey = crypto.randomBytes(32);" if you've pretty-printed the file (which you'll probably need to do).  I *think* that's the code that generates the private key if you create a *new* account using the "+" button to the right of "Account" in "Deploy and Run Transactions".  Breakpoint there, copy the private key and use the new account.  I'm sure this isn't a long-term solution, but might get you what you need very temporarily?

Comment: thanks I'll have a look later now still stuck doing something else outside of remix on solidity but this may be very good info....will update if i find a way too.

Comment: This is a question to ask to the support forum of remix... they know exactly if some answer does exist!

Answer (score 8):

You can find the list of private keys here:

https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/blob/d13fea7e8429436de6622d855bf75688c664a956/libs/remix-simulator/src/methods/accounts.ts

```
Private key                                                         Address
503f38a9c967ed597e47fe25643985f032b072db8075426a92110f82df48dfcb    0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4
7e5bfb82febc4c2c8529167104271ceec190eafdca277314912eaabdb67c6e5f    0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2
cc6d63f85de8fef05446ebdd3c537c72152d0fc437fd7aa62b3019b79bd1fdd4    0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db
638b5c6c8c5903b15f0d3bf5d3f175c64e6e98a10bdb9768a2003bf773dcb86a    0x78731D3Ca6b7E34aC0F824c42a7cC18A495cabaB
f49bf239b6e554fdd08694fde6c67dac4d01c04e0dda5ee11abee478983f3bc0    0x617F2E2fD72FD9D5503197092aC168c91465E7f2
adeee250542d3790253046eee928d8058fd544294a5219bea152d1badbada395    0x17F6AD8Ef982297579C203069C1DbfFE4348c372
097ffe12069dcb3c3d99e6771e2cbf491a9b8b2f93ff4d3468f550c5e8264755    0x5c6B0f7Bf3E7ce046039Bd8FABdfD3f9F5021678
5f58e8b9f1867ef00578b6f03e159428ab168f776aa445bc3ecdb02c7db8e865    0x03C6FcED478cBbC9a4FAB34eF9f40767739D1Ff7
290e721ac87c7b3f31bef7b70104b9280ed3fa1425a59451490c9c02bf50d08f    0x1aE0EA34a72D944a8C7603FfB3eC30a6669E454C
27efe944ff128cf510ab447b529eec28772f13bf65ebf1cbd504192c4f26e9d8    0x0A098Eda01Ce92ff4A4CCb7A4fFFb5A43EBC70DC
3cd7232cd6f3fc66a57a6bedc1a8ed6c228fff0a327e169c2bcc5e869ed49511    0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c
2ac6c190b09897cd8987869cc7b918cfea07ee82038d492abce033c75c1b1d0c    0x14723A09ACff6D2A60DcdF7aA4AFf308FDDC160C
dae9801649ba2d95a21e688b56f77905e5667c44ce868ec83f82e838712a2c7a    0x4B0897b0513fdC7C541B6d9D7E929C4e5364D2dB
d74aa6d18aa79a05f3473dd030a97d3305737cbc8337d940344345c1f6b72eea    0x583031D1113aD414F02576BD6afaBfb302140225
71975fbf7fe448e004ac7ae54cad0a383c3906055a65468714156a07385e96ce    0xdD870fA1b7C4700F2BD7f44238821C26f7392148
```